# Update from Express checkout to Adaptive checkout

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal

I have already implemented Express checkout in php but found that express checkout for recurring payments does not work for german payers from paypal support and they advice to use pre-approved method insted.

From some R&D,I found that pre-approved method comes under the Adaptive Payments API.

Hence,Is there anyone who implemented same? I haven't find any appropriate respond on net so asking here

1) Should I require to completely remove functionality implementation of Express Checkout and add Adaptive Payments insted and It seems major changes in work that already done?

2) Is there any more payment my client should require to done for this ?

Is parallel checkout itself Adaptive payment checkout ?

I have got below link but not sure this is Adaptive Checkout

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/

Any advice will be much appreciate !!

Answer (score 0):

That link is not Adaptive Payments; it is for Express Checkout, specifically how to do parallel payments within Express Checkout, which is not what you are trying to do. AP and EC are separate lines of PayPal products, so anything that has EC in the name is not AP, and vice versa. You can google for the Adaptive pages, e.v.:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

However: I am not certain that PayPal support was intending to direct you away from Express Checkout to Adaptive Payments. While EC and AP have failrly distinctive names that are not easy to confuse, the feature sets within those two product families are much more confusing, e.g.: subscriptions, reference transactions, recurring payments, preapproved payments, billing agreements, etc. Part of this confusion comes from PayPal reusing names when adding similar/compatible features to multiple product lines, and other times trying to differentiate & use distinct names... and then sometimes RENAMING the features. So for example Preapproved Payments was first offered in EC, but then this same functionality was upgraded & renamed Reference Transactions. Then AP implemented a similar feature and called it Preapproved Payments. Then PayPal added similar functionality to their RESTful APIs and called it Billing Agreements, which was a term that was originally used to describe the agreements that were set up in EC's original version of Preapproved Payments. Yikes!

Anyway, apologies for the confusion -- that is what happens when a company keeps building (and buying) more and more product lines over 15 years (and never clearly deprecates & retires any of them).

But I can clear up the terminology a little bit:

"Recurring payments" is generally used to refer to scenarios where you the merchant tell PayPal the schedule on which to bill the customer and PayPal initiates those payments on your behalf. "Preapproved Payments" (and the many synonyms/similar features) is generally used to refer to scenarios where you the merchant obtain agreement to bill the customer in the future, but (usually) you the merchant would manage the schedule and initiate those payments. (And sometimes "recurring payments" can be considered as subset of the broader category of "preapproved payents" but lets try to keep this relatively simple....)

In any case: preapproved payments aka reference transaction functionality should be available within Express Checkout in Germany. In short both EC and AP will support you billing the customer again in the future, but neither product will support recurring billing where PayPal initiates those future payments on a fixed schedule. So if you want to stick with EC you should be able to do that.

Seea also this StackExchange post from a few years ago:

[Paypal - API Checkout (Rec. payment) - Sandbox Test Accounts - German account always set to "Premier"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265288/paypal-api-checkout-rec-payment-sandbox-test-accounts-german-account-al)